# Android: How ListView works

Tags: android

For example I have my custom ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter, it has **two** groups.

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowgroup, parent, false);
        }
        s++;
        Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(s));
        return convertView;
    }
```

**First question:** Why this code will always return in LogCat Index = 1, Index = 2, Index = 3, ... , Index = 10?

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            s++;
            Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(s));
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowgroup, parent, false);
        }
            return convertView;
        }
```

**Second question:** Why this code will return in LogCat Index = 1, Index = 2, Index = 3? I have only 2 groups, not 3. If I add one more group, the Index value will be 4. I set breakpoint in **convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowgroup, parent, false);** line and I saw that getGroupView with *groupPosition==0* executed at the beginning and at the end.

It is my mistake or so it should be? I want to understand why this's happening =)

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I found the answer [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) =) Before that I do not understand how it works.